# Display Post content on Category Page

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module, wordpress

I have the FishPig wordpress/magento integration.

I'd like to be able to display a blog post in a category much like you can display a native static CMS block.

I had expected that the associated blog post feature achieved this, is that the case?

If not how can this be achieved?

Comment: Is this Magento 1 or 2?

Comment: It's Magento version 1.9.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can update the **app > design > frontend > your_package > your_theme > template > catalog > category > view.phtml** template and add code to display a post, the code below will show your blogs most recent post.

You can filter this to display a post from a specific category or any of the other filter Fishpig offers.

```
<?php
$posts = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post_collection')
    ->addPostTypeFilter('post')
    ->setOrderByPostDate()
    ->addIsViewableFilter()
    ->setPageSize(1)
    ->load();
?>

<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?></a>
                <?php if ($image = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $post->getAvailableImage() ?>" src="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>" />
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <p><?php echo $post->getPostExcerpt(40) ?></p></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Toggle post per category**

If you want to be able to toggle the post to show per category you can add a custom Yes/No category attribute, then write some logic if this is set to yes display a post using the above code.

Comment: Will this not effect all magento categories?

Comment: I have added some info how I would enable you to toggle this per category